# Optimal critic in Wasserstein GAN (WGAN)

Tags: generative-models, gan, wasserstein

In the Wasserstein GAN (generative adversarial network) paper they say that the **critic** needs to be optimal.
What does this mean *practically*?

They do more training iterations of critic (5) than the **generator** (1).  In some papers on WGANs they train a critic for 50 or 100 times more then generator for first 20 epochs.

I do not understand why it is done, particularly what does "optimality" means in terms of implementation. How can you find out whether your critic is in optimum (is it about the balance of parameters or Wasserstein loss values)?

Is there a causal way to determine the ration of critic and generator iterations for a particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

Compared with vanilla CAN,  optimal D in WGAN may not cause the problem of gradient vanishing. Stronger discriminators have better  ability for measuring distance between P(real)and P(fake). Perhaps this is why the discriminator should train much more time in WGAN.